# Why does DNS resolve www.google.com and google.com returned different result?

Tags: dns, dig

I don't know how to ask this question appropriately.Maybe it is a duplicate one, if so, please let me know.
When I use `dig` to resolve `www.google.com` and `google.com`, it gives me different answer.Why? Please refer me to articles relative to this.Thanks:-)

Comment: first: this is very off-topic for SO. second: because `www.google.com` is a different domain name than `google.com`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`www.google.com` and `google.com` are separate DNS entries and can point to two different servers. For most sites one is just a CNAME of the other, meaning that they both end up pointing to the same server, but this is not a requirement.

Historically NASA has been reluctant to support `nasa.gov` for www at all, and [this blog post](https://blogs.nasa.gov/nasadotgov/2011/05/31/post_1306860816073/) makes an interesting read.

Comment: Thanks for your reply:-)